# Trying to scrape a NY times article, but scrapes slideshow instead

Tags: python, html, request, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am having a weird problem with my code

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from bs4.diagnose import diagnose
    import requests

    def get_text(url):
        data=""
        p=requests.get(url).content
        soup=BeautifulSoup(p)    
        paragraphs=soup.select("p.story-body-text.story-content")
        data=p
        text=""
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            text+=paragraph.text
        text=text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        return str(text)
```

Basically what my code should be doing is getting the html by using "requests" and then using BS4 to find all the "p.story-body-text.story-content" which contains the actual article content.
It works great on some articles such as: 
http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/10/world/asia/malaysia-airlines-flight.html?ref=world&_r=0

and 
http://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/13/world/asia/coalition-building-season-in-india.html?

However, it will not work on these links:

http://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/06/world/middleeast/break-in-syrian-war-brings-brittle-calm.html?_r=0#

and

http://www.nytimes.com/2014/02/23/magazine/instagram-travel-diary.html?nav

I think it is a problem with the "requests" library because it does not fetch the correct HTML 
Any ideas?
Edit: pastebin link  http://pastebin.com/n3svnKTQ

Comment: I am able to get the text using your code on all 4 links.

Comment: That is weird. What version of requests do you have?